# Putting markers on google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to put two separate markers on two separate maps that are positioned side by side on my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map, map2;

function initialize(condition) {
// create the maps
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.594700, -105.221787),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var myOptions1 = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.104441, -106.575394),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}


map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), 
myOptions1);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [simple maker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) for this.

Just place this in your code after `map = new Google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);`:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.594700, -105.221787),
    map: map,
    title: 'Marker 1'
});
```

And after `map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), 
myOptions1);`:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.104441, -106.575394),
    map: map2,
    title: 'Marker 2'
});
```

---

### Example

Your code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map, map2;

function initialize(condition) {
// create the maps
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.594700, -105.221787),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.594700, -105.221787),
    map: map,
    title: 'Marker 1'
});

var myOptions1 = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.104441, -106.575394),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}


map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), 
myOptions1);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.104441, -106.575394),
    map: map2,
    title: 'Marker 2'
});

}
</script>
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

That code by itself will not put any markers on the map, it will simply render the maps, with each one centred on the latitude/longitude you specify.

Look at the first example on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers for an idea of how to add a marker to each of your maps.